# Add decoration at end of chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, book-design

A half full page at the end of a chapter nicely signals that the chapter ends. However, sometimes the last page of a chapter looks a bit too empty if there are are only, say, 5-10 lines. In some older books you find the whitespace at the end of chapters being filled with some sort of decorative line, as in the image below.

[image]

Is there a way to define a command that measures the `fill` in the last page of the chapter and adds a decoration if it is more than certain length, perhaps `.7\textwidth`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\kant[1-3]

%\decoration

\chapter{Chapter two}
\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter one}
\kant[1-3]

%\decoration
\ifdim\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal-\baselineskip\relax>.7\textheight
\begin{center}
\rule{3cm}{2pt}
\end{center}
\fi
\chapter{Chapter two}
\kant[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following uses x,y-coordinate labels/markers to measure the end-of-chapter fill, inserting a `\chapterdecoration` (you can change this) whenever there's more than 70% of the `\textheight` remaining.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{eso-pic,zref-savepos}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*{%
    \AtTextLowerLeft{%
      \zsaveposy{page-bottom}% Save text lower y coordinate
    }%
  }%
}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{%
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0\relax
    \unskip
    \zsaveposy{chap-\thechapter-y}% Save chapter's last line y coordinate
  \fi
  \insertchapterdecoration
  \oldchapter
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \zsaveposy{chap-\thechapter-y}% Save last chapter's last line y coordinate
  \insertchapterdecoration}

\newcommand{\insertchapterdecoration}{%
  \ifdim\dimexpr\zposy{chap-\thechapter-y}sp-\zposy{page-bottom}sp+\baselineskip>.7\textheight
    \chapterdecoration
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\chapterdecoration}{%
  \vfill
  \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\rule{.3\textwidth}{5pt}}\par%
  \vfill
}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\kant[1-3]

\chapter{Chapter two}
\kant[1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to this over the other answer, other than that the decoration command does not need to be manually inserted?